# How to stop a repeating alarm manually(without code) using android monitor of android studio.

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager

I am trying to use AlarmManager class in android and i set the time of repeat to after every 10 seconds.Now after running the app the activity which i mentioned in my code after the alarm is set gets called after every 10 seconds properly.

But the problem is even after i press the back button(to call onStop method) of my phone,the app again calls the activity.So,i pressed the "close" button in android monitor of android studio,but then also the activity gets called after every 10 seconds.

So,i want to know how can i manually close this app and why is this happening ?

Here is the code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,0);
        Log.d("asd","initialized alarmintent");

        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),10000, alarmIntent);

                        Log.d("asd", "alarm set");


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cancel the alarm in `onDestroy()` of your activity.

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

 alarmManager.cancel(<your_pending_intent>);
```

Comment: `onStop()` may be the better choice and moving this initialization code to `onStart()`. `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: @dharms In that case,there will no alarm even if the user presses home button . I don't think this is the desired behavior.

Comment: `onPause()` is called when you use the home button.

Comment: But onStop() is called after onPause().

Comment: @ShadabAnsari  when i add onStop(),then the activity gets called only one time even if i dont press the back button .why??

Comment: "then the activity gets called only one time" - what do you mean by that? Can you explain it ?

Comment: i mean to say that the activity should be getting called repeatedly until i press the back button.

Comment: but the activity gets called only one time.

Comment: I'm still not getting what do you mean when you say " activity gets called " . Does it means onCreate() doesn't gets called ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108338/discussion-between-a874-and-shadab-ansari).